# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 2) after upgrading to Rails 3.1 using activerecord-sqlserver-adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

After upgrading to Rails 3.1 any ActiveRecord call has the following result:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:185:in `select'
from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:9:in `select_all'
from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:62:in `select_all'
from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/base.rb:469:in `find_by_sql'
from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:106:in `to_a'
from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:155:in `all'
from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc1/lib/active_record/base.rb:440:in `all'
from (irb):1
from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need to update to the master branch of the sql server adapter. It will be the eventual 3.1 version. 3.0 versions of the adapter are for 3.0 rails. So your adapter is out of date.

Answer (score 11):

check your gemfile, you need the newest mysql2 gem for rails 3 to work:

replace

```
gem 'mysql2',  '0.2.7'
```

with

```
gem 'mysql2',  '>=0.3'
```

and run a "bundle install" and you should be good to go

Comment: If you are using sql-logging gem, you should update it to version 3.0.6